# How can I protect an mp4 file that is being called from the same folder as the index.html that contains the video element?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mp4

First of all I want to address something I know others will mention - I KNOW someone can just record their screen and I KNOW that there will always be security holes.

That being said, here is my issue;

So we have a webpage, that webpage contains a video element and it's src is simply 'testVid.mp4', due to it being in the same folder on an AWS EC2 server.

The issue we have is that anyone can click the mp4 link in the element inspector and open the file in a new page and download it.

I created an expressJS server and API on my local machine, and created a protected route so that the video link only works when called by the correct referrer and a few other things. This worked AMAZINGLY.

The issue is now, we cannot move the files from the EC2 or even move them around on the EC2 so I need to devise a solution that prevents users from having access to the video's url directly that doesn't involve an express server.

Can anyone please advise me on how this may be accomplished?

Comment: So you want to do the same thing you are doing with Express, but with something other than Express? What specifically do you want to use other than Express? Do you want to use Nginx? Do you want to use Apache? You need to be specific about what you want to do. And since you figured out what checks you want to make ("referrer and a few other things") you should be able to search for how to do those same things in whatever other web server tool you decide to use.

Comment: H @MarkB thanks for replying! So you're saying regardless of anything, I will need to set up a local server on my EC2 server? I've done a bit more digging and am currently trying out a php solution, where I point my src to test.php and that returns the file if requirements are met. Do you think that will be another dead end?

Comment: "I KNOW someone can just record their screen" People don't even need to record the screen. Serving the file directly like you are doing requires the browser to download the entire file to the local computer before it can play the video. So all someone has to do is go to their browser's cache folder to find the video file. I suggest reading up on how you can use AWS CloudFront for video streaming: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/streaming/

Comment: "So you're saying regardless of anything, I will need to set up a local server on my EC2 server?" Something has to serve the file somehow. You will always need a server of some sort. You can't just copy the file to a random folder on a file system and expect people to be able to view that file in their web browsers.

Comment: Sorry @MarkB you are being confusing - The EC2 itself is a server, If I place the video filepath as the video element's src I can visit the webpage on my local machine (not on the EC2) and see the video just fine so I'm not sure what you are trying to say?

Comment: @MarkB The cloudfront comment was very enlightening, thanks for that

Comment: The EC2 itself is a virtual machine. You have to have **Web Server Software** running on that virtual machine that will *serve* the file on the Internet. Viewing it locally is totally different, because your web browser is running on the same computer that the file is on, so it isn't making Internet requests for those files. If all you had to do is copy a file to an EC2 instance to make it available to web browsers on the Internet, then nothing would be secure on EC2 instances at all. People would be able to download your entire instance.

Comment: @MarkB I tried to make it very clear, When I say local machine, I meant not the VM... the files don't exist on my local machine. I can visit the the index.html from any computer as long as I have the VMs address - so isn't that making internet requests?

Comment: If there is a `index.html` file on the EC2 instance, and you can view that file in the web browser on your local computer, then there is web server **software** installed and running on that EC2 instance that is making that file available to the public Internet.

Comment: @camelMilk_ _"...When called by the correct referrer and a few other things."_ PHP has capabilities to check the referrer before serving a file, so it might help you to recreate your ExpressJS settings. **(2)** If your _"protect"_ actually means _"hide the video URL"_ then you could try serving the video bytes directly into the video tag. Use either MSE with PHP to feed dynamic "chunks" from the MP4, or use PHP to alone to feed correct video bytes directly into a video tag (since streaming bytes removes seeking, you manually send the correct bytes needed to play for that required time point).